# What is the purpose of "Enable native XMLHTTP support" option in IE

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, memory-leaks, xmlhttprequest

Our website uses AJAX call and uses `XMLHTTPRequest` to acheive that. When client uses an single IE instance through out the day and countinously navigating and refesing the page with in that IE, we end up with out of memory exception and forced to close the IE.

By enabling the option `Enable native XMLHTTP support` in Advnaced tab of IE fixes the issue. Since we prefers native XMLHTTP object over ActiveXObject, the exception might be caused due to using ActiveXObject. But still not sure what could be the root cause or is there any other better way to solve the issue. We use IE8. We have never encounterd any such issue in other browsers(Firefox and chrome). Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/Pita/etherpad-lite/wiki/How-to-enable-native-XMLHTTP-support-in-IE

Comment: @Quoi , this is not an answer. It's just another case.

Comment: Do I understand right? IE has a built-in, standards-compliant XHR implementation but disabled it by default?

Answer (score 6):

Enable native XMLHTTP support means that the browser will not provide MSXML.HttpRequest but instead window.XMLHttpRequest that is standards compliant. We successfully used however both versions without any leakage whatsoever, so I guess it must be some implementation issue in your code - I am just guessing, but pinning MSXML.HttpRequest instances on DOMNodes (via an eventlistener) can lead to such situations.

Comment: @ Peter Aron Zentai  -  pinning MSXML.HttpRequest instances on DOMNodes (via an eventlistener) can lead to such situations. -> Can you kindly give me an example for this

Comment: $('#myButton').click( function() { var xhr = createXHR(); xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {  }});  <-- this might keep the whole XHR response in memory as the xhr object with the reposnse body is pinned through a closure var that will only gets gc-d is the button disappears.

Comment: how will i dispose the xhr then and where would be the best place to dispose xhr.

Comment: ActiveXObject will be created here right as we prefer xmlhttp?

Answer (score 2):

"Enable native XMLHTTP support” option in IE, unsurprisingly, makes IE provide native support for XMLHTTPRequest. If you don't enable this, you'll only have legacy ActiveX binding to MSXML library in IE. I guess you use some library that provides cross-browser handling for cases where native support is absent (setting turned off or older IE that only have legacy interface) or manually fallback to MSXML. Since MSXML binding is an alien interface for JavaScript, there are many places where objects introduced from outside JS can form cross-references with native objects, not letting either JS or ActiveX garbage collector to reclaim them, since they don't communicate and can't find such circular references.

Best solution, in my opinion, is to recommend IE7 users to always have this option on (there's really zero drawbacks to it) and just forget about older browsers. If this is not an option somehow, try recursively clear all MSXML objects you create in your fallback code.

Comment: Building a solution on an Advanced setting in IE is just not working. Nobody ever goes there to switch anything even if you suggest...

Comment: It is generally never disabled in older browsers unless some paranoid group policies are in use and simply doesn't exists in newer. I don't suggest completely throwing away MSXML, but it is really about time to stop caring about its less than stellar performances.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you are leaking XMLHTTPRequest objects, due to circular refrerences between the HTML DOM, the JavaScript execution engine, and the XMLHTTPRequest object.

You need to unhook the events and dereference the XMLHttp objects when the request completes. (To dereference them make sure no JavaScript object or variable references them, including the little bits of script in the onClick handlers etc.

Enabling native XMLHTTPRequest means that the external component is taken out of the loop, so the DOM is able to manage the request lifetime itself.

See also @PeterAronZentai's answer.

Comment: little bit of code example would really help to me! Thanks a lot

Comment: I am guessing you have a page open, with lots of Ajax, but you never actually reload the whole page?

Comment: ActiveXObject will be created here right as we prefer xmlhttp?